# Using transformers for information extraction

Tags: nlp, information-retrieval

#### Task

I am trying to do some information extraction on earnings reports. I am trying to extract certain metrics, e.g. net sales for quarters. The earnings reports differ quite a lot in how they are structured but they use similar language. A "simple" example follows

> Nine-month period in figures
>
> Order bookings increased 6.6% to SEK 1,095.5 million (1,027.9).
>
> Net sales rose 22.8% to SEK 1,153.5 million (939.4). Adjusted for currency fluctuations, sales increased 19.6%.
>
> Operating profit rose 31.3% to SEK 171.8 million (130.8), corresponding to an operating margin of 14.9% (13.9). Adjusted for currency fluctuations, operating profit increased 24.5%.
>
> Profit before tax amounted to SEK 176.3 million (137.9).
>
> This result includes nonrecurring items (refer to page 10 of the attached interim report). These items had a positive net effect of SEK 1.4 million on operating profit.
>
> Cash flow after changes in working capital amounted to SEK 215.2 million (180.4).
>
> Third quarter in figures
>
> Order bookings increased 10.3% to SEK 431.1 million (390.7). Of the order bookings during the quarter, 25% were recognized during the third quarter and 32% to 42% pertain to revenue within 12 months after the end of the quarter.
>
> Net sales increased 38.8% to **SEK 457.4 million**, while it was SEK 329.5 million in the previous year. Adjusted for currency fluctuations, sales increased 34.9%.
>
> Operating profit rose 98.6% to SEK 99.7 million (50.2), corresponding to an operating margin of 21.8% (15.2). Adjusted for currency fluctuations, operating profit increased 87.6%.
> Profit before tax amounted to SEK 100.7 million (51.4).
>
> This result includes nonrecurring items (refer to page 10 of the attached interim report). These items had a positive net effect of SEK 1.4 million on operating profit.
>
> Cash flow after changes in working capital amounted to SEK 134.1 million (80.0).

where I have highlighted the metric I want to extract.

Note that `Third quarter in figures` is important, i.e. information from previous phrases are needed.

#### Initial approach

My first strategy is to extract all candidate spans (`SEK 1,095.5 million`, `SEK 1,153.5 million` etc.) and then classify each one of them (`EXTRACT` or `DO_NOT_EXTRACT`), but I haven't got any great results with that approach. I was thinking that maybe I could exploit transformer models like BERT etc. to capture context from previous phrases?

I hope someone have a good idea on how to tackle this task.